# Safe way to create singleton with init method in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I would like to take the GCD approach of using shared instances to the next step so I created the following code:

```
@implementation MyClass

static id sharedInstance;

#pragma mark Initialization

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    if (sharedInstance) {
        return sharedInstance;
    }
    @synchronized(self) {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            sharedInstance = self;
        }
        return self;
    }
}

@end
```

I assume the `sharedInstance` method seems to be ok but I am unsure about the init method. The reason for creating this is that I don't want people using my SDK, to use the init method, and if they do ... make it bullet proof.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of transparently redirecting calls to `init` to the singleton implementation which can cause very confusing behaviour for the users of your SDK, I suggest not allowing to call init at all:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:@"..." userInfo:nil];
}

- (instancetype)initPrivate {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: (self = [super init]) throws a warning and init without return nil will stop xcode from compiling ... it was in my edit

Comment: @Ondrej the missing return can easily be "fixed" by using `@throw` instead of `[NSException raise:]`. And the `(self = [super init])` pattern doesn't create a warning, you must have something else messing it up.

Comment: Why not use `+initialize` to initialize the singleton instance?

Comment: @Hyperbole there is no reason not to, if you prefer that option. So why not use the `dispatch_once` pattern ;) ?

Comment: @Hyperbole: Because using dispatch_once is an established pattern for all kinds of things; dispatch_once is used exactly where the functionality is needed, whereas +initialize code is written in a totally different place from where it is needed. Also with dispatch_once it is possible to call class methods that configure the singleton object before creating it. And dispatch_once can be used in C++ or C code, so you need to learn only once and use only one method.

Comment: @Leo I asked because I've yet to get a cogent response.  I use `+initialize` because it's called once per instance, is inherently thread-safe and requires no outside API knowledge.  I don't have a particular argument against `dispatch_once`, just a wondering.  Thanks, btw.

Comment: @gnasher729 I see your points, though I'd suggest that you're combining unrelated functionality by initializing and returning in the same function scope.  Why initialize and return in the same place?  There's already a location for initialization that's thread safe and guaranteed to run once by the runtime without polluting the namespace with a new static variable and adding more code to a method that declares it only returns a shared instance.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to suggest new ways of solving your problem.

You can use `NS_UNAVAILABLE` in the header file just like this:

```
//Header file
@interface MyClass : NSObject
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
//...
@end
```

In this case `init` function will not be available from outside, will not be suggested for autocompletion, and you'll be able to normally use the `init` method inside implementation file.

As you are making a singleton class I would suggest you to make `new` method unavailable too by adding this line to the header file:

```
+ (instancetype)new NS_UNAVAILABLE;
```

There is also an old way of making methods unavailable (which can be used in header too):

```
- (instancetype) init __attribute__((unavailable("Use 'sharedInstance' instead of 'init' as this class is singleton.")));
```

This can be used if you want to prompt some message about unavailability.

Comment: This is not true with Xcode 7.3: no matter NS_UNAVAILABLE or the old way, Xcode will prompt compiler error saying the `sharedInstance` implementation can't use `init` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The general opinion is that trying to protect your singleton against that kind of bug is pointless. Whoever calls `[[LUIMain alloc] init]` and creates a singleton gets what they deserved.

And the code that you wrote isn't thread safe anyway. If I call `[[LUIMain alloc] init]` while someone else calls *sharedInstance*, sharedInstance will return a different object than on the next call. (`@synchronized (self)` in the init method is pointless, because a second caller will have a different self).