# Objective C - Creating singleton using shared instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have doubts regarding the creation of singleton class in Objective-C/iOS.
Where ever I see the trick to create a singleton class in objective-C is this code

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

Whenever I call `[MyManager sharedManager]` of course I get the same address. However, I can also write `[MyManager new]` in which case the address is different.

1.Isn't the concept of singleton class is that it restricts the instantiation of a class to one object?

2.If we can create another object its not a singleton anymore, is it?

In my iOS app I tried `[UIApplication new]`. I got an exception in runtime. Now this I get. You cannot make another instance of UIApplication since its a singleton class.

So why the use of shared instance considered to be the way of creating a singleton class or have I got this all wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29748314/2442804 might be helpful for you.

Comment: Your statement *"The compiler threw an exception in runtime"* does not make any sense btw. At runtime there is no compiler ;) It simply is a runtime exception which is thrown because you as the dev do something the designer of the framework does not allow.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sharedManager` is the convenience method you'd use to access the singleton instance. While this doesn't guarantee that there will be only one instance of that manager over the app, if everyone is using `sharedManager` then there will practically exist only one instance of that manager.

This kind of singletons are singletons by convenience, not by implementation. You should use them, for multiple reasons:

- you can unit test them, by calling `alloc init` in your unit tests and making use of that brand new allocated object
- it makes your life easier if decide to later refactor the manager and no longer use it as a singleton if you consider it from the begging like a regular object to work with

Of-course, you can make a singleton by-the-book by overriding the `init` and `allocWithZone:` to either return the only instance or by raising an exception, however I'm not sure they'd worth the effort.

There's a very good tech talk regarding singletons held by Misko Hevery in the [Google clean code talks](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL693EFD059797C21E) playlist, the link to the video: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI&list=PL693EFD059797C21E&index=2). This kind of singletons are referred  as lower case `S` singletons, not capital `S` ones in the video, and Misko explains very well why they are preferred.

Comment: _singletons by convenience, not by implementation_. Ok maybe the definition of singleton should not be that restrictive. Thanks.

Comment: This kind of singletons are referred  as lower case `S` singletons, not capital `S` ones in the video I referenced in my answer, and Mikso explains very well why they are preferred.

Comment: Great, one more detail to look for.

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't break singleton concept. You choose your way to implement what you want. If you want to create only singleton instance, you can make run error by override init function:

   ```
     [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
      reason:@"bla bla bla..." userInfo:nil];
   ```

or

2. you can override it to force return to shared instance.
   Of course, you can. But it not recommend if you are using singleton.

Comment: Wiki says "_the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object_". How does that not break singleton concept?

Answer (score -1):

Objective-C uses a pragmatic approach. Your +sharedManager method returns a singleton. If someone is stupid enough to call [SingletonClass new] or [[SingletonClass alloc] init], that's their problem. They'll get what they deserve. There is no reason to prevent people from shooting themselves in the foot if that is what they want to do.

There are millions of programming errors that people can make and that the developer of a class or the compiler cannot prevent. No point wasting effort on preventing this particular error.